# Is this use case UML correct?

Tags: uml

I just wanted to know is this correct and does it meet UML requirements?
I have a problem with Login Customer and Customer Registration use cases and i think I over complicated things.

[Image of my UML diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mUUr.png)

Comment: Login is no UC (there's no added value). It's a constraint that can apply to other UCs. I'd avoid the use of extend/include since it's usually applied in functional decomposition (UC are about added value). Else it looks ok. You should use strict predicate/subject[/object] notation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can see that there's no added value to UC  as login but thats the problem i dont understand how come customer registration is a UC.

Comment: Customer registration is a UC as it causes adding account of new user in a system. It can be the only thing someone does and it still has some effect (account is created). On the other hand if you login, do nothing and logout there is no change in the system.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, your UCs are basically fine except for the `Login` as it does not add value. Is `Register as customer` a use case and where is its added value? Now, that's where it's starting to get philosophical. One could argue: the added value of `Login` is that I gain access to something, similar to `Register`. So there is only a little margin between the one being a valid UC and the other not. Taking it serious you could put `Register` also in the non-UC drawer. However, while login is just a dozen keyboard strokes and a mouse click, a registration is somewhat more complex. And usually you connect more added value with that in the background. In most cases you want to retrieve information about the registered person that can be used (here's the word again!) to (take Facebook) sell him products (he does not need).

To sum up, a UC adds value (not necessarily to the primary actor, but to some place of the system under consideration) which might not be directly visible.